# MySQL update errors with "Subquery returns more than 1 row" despite lack of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I have a query on mysql 5.1.56:

```
select * from team_member_accounts where node = 33136
```

...that returns exactly one row.  However, the following query errors with `Subquery returns more than 1 row`:

```
update team_member_accounts
set fee_remaining = 0,
    loan_account_balance = 35000,
    reimbursable_amount = 0, 
    reimbursed_amount = 0
where node = 33136
```

Um...what?  What subquery?  And how is it more than one row?

Comment: Are there any triggers on that table?

Comment: Is team_member_accounts a real table, or is it a view (which could be a combination of selects across multiple tables)?

Comment: triggers!  totally forgot.  thanks@MarcB!  (and it was a real table)

Comment: @MarcB: As far as I understand notifications, I'd guess that you did not receive one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table likely has a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

may be try this one
update team_member_accounts
set fee_remaining = 0,
    loan_account_balance = 35000,
    reimbursable_amount = 0, 
    reimbursed_amount = 0
where node = (SELECT DISTINCT(NODE) FROM team_member_accounts where node = 33136)

if it doesnt work, i think strange in your table